# Are there multiple ways of converting Quaternions to Euler Angles?

Tags: rotations, quaternions

Today, I discovered something about rotation matrices in in the source code of Blender. There is a function, that returns two different euler angles showing the rotation of a given rotation matrix. They use two different euler calculation methods, to late choose the euler angle that fits best to whatever criteria. Here is the code snippet:

```
cy = hypotf(mat[i][i], mat[i][j]);
eul1[i] = atan2f(mat[j][k], mat[k][k]);
eul1[j] = atan2f(-mat[i][k], cy);
eul1[k] = atan2f(mat[i][j], mat[i][i]);

eul2[i] = atan2f(-mat[j][k], -mat[k][k]);
eul2[j] = atan2f(-mat[i][k], -cy);
eul2[k] = atan2f(-mat[i][j], -mat[i][i]);
```

Now I wonder, can we also calculate these two eulers from a Quaternion, instead of a rotation matrix? So far, I know one way of converting quaternions to eulers. Which is ...

```
pitchYawRoll1.y = Atan2 (2f * q.x * q.w + 2f * q.y * q.z, 1 - 2f * (q.z * q.z + q.w * q.w));   // Yaw
pitchYawRoll1.x = Asin (2f * (q.x * q.z - q.w * q.y));                                         // Pitch
pitchYawRoll1.z = Atan2 (2f * q.x * q.y + 2f * q.z * q.w, 1 - 2f * (q.y * q.y + q.z * q.z));   // Roll
```

I tried to do the conversion the second way (see `eul2` from Blender), but the result is not showing the same rotation as the original quaternion `q` ...

```
pitchYawRoll2.y = Atan2 (-(2f * q.x * q.w + 2f * q.y * q.z), -(1 - 2f * (q.z * q.z + q.w * q.w))); // Yaw
pitchYawRoll2.x = -Asin (2f * (q.x * q.z - q.w * q.y));                                           // Pitch
pitchYawRoll2.z = Atan2 (-(2f * q.x * q.y + 2f * q.z * q.w), -(1 - 2f * (q.y * q.y + q.z * q.z))); // Roll
```

I think `pitchYawRoll2.x` is calculated incorrectly, because `atan2(0.4,-0.3)` is not equal to `-atan2(0.4.0.3)`. (I know the result of `Asin (2f * (q.x * q.z - q.w * q.y))` and i assume it equals `atan2(x,y)`. But I don't know how to reconstruct `atan2(x,-y)` from it)

Is there a way to get two the two euler angles from a quaternion as its done in Blender?

*Hope the question is not too confusion. I am new to Rotations and the Quaternion representation.*

Comment: Well, the first thing about converting to Euler angles is [figuring out which of the six conventions you're going to use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Conventions).  Some people consider this a great reason not to use Euler angles :)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I use ZYX order, but i don't know about Blender

Comment: Just gonna have to read the code or documentation, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding and trying out more, I found the solution. In the blender code you can use any angle axis order if you set i,j,k accordingly. In my case, i need YXZ order, because I'm using Unity (i=1; j=0; k=2). The only thing left to do is converting the Quaternion `q` to a rotation matrix, and then converting the matrix to the two euler angles as Blender does it. Thank you for your suggestions!